# How can I use Bash to contract/shrink a set of values

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Let's say I have values

```
value-al-keddka
value-al-aljdf;
value-al-dkdl;a
```

I need output as

```
value-al-{keddka, aljdf;, dkdl;a}
```

or simply

```
value-al-*
```

Similarly

```
valuealkeddka
valuealaljdf;
valuealdkdl;a
```

to

```
valueal{keddka, aljdf;, dkdl;a}
```

or

```
valueal*
```

How can I accomplish this using bash?

Answer (score 2):

Perl one-liner for `value-al-{keddka, aljdf;, dkdl;a}` output:

```
$ perl -F- -lanE 'push @{$vals{$F[0]}{$F[1]}}, $F[2];
                  END { $"=","; while (($v1,$h1) = each %vals) { while (($v2, $v3) = each %$h1) { say "$v1-$v2-{@$v3}" }}}' input.txt
```

Or using [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) and sed for the same output:

```
$ datamash -Ws -t- groupby 1,2 collapse 3 < input.txt | sed -E 's/^([^-]+-[^-]+-)(.*)/\1{\2}/'
```

Or for `value-al-*` output:

```
$ cut -d- -f1,2 input.txt | sort -u | sed -e 's/$/-*/'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sorry that I was too specific on my question. I need to group this also
```valuealkeddka
valuealjdf;``` to `valueal*`